# Calling a vectorized operation in Octave for multiple output

Tags: matlab, if-statement, merge, vectorization, octave

I would like to make a vectorized ifelse/merge operation on some data. To avoid unnecessary comparisons, I would like to obtain a result by calling ifelse command only once. Here is my example code:

```
aaa = [90 80 70 60];
bbb = [10 15 20 30];
ccc = [ 0  3  6  9];
res = ifelse(ccc > 5, {[aaa bbb]}, {[aaa*-1 bbb*-1]})
```

Since I could run the ifelse command with cell arrays, I am getting the repetitive results as below:

```
{
  [1,1] = -90  -80  -70  -60  -10  -15  -20  -30
  [1,2] = -90  -80  -70  -60  -10  -15  -20  -30
  [1,3] =  90   80   70   60   10   15   20   30
  [1,4] =  90   80   70   60   10   15   20   30
}
```

However, the result what I want from ifelse command is as below:

```
[-90 -80 70 60]
[-10 -15 20 30]
```

Actually, I can do it by calling the ifelse command twice, as follows:

```
res1 = ifelse(ccc > 5, aaa, aaa*-1)
res2 = ifelse(ccc > 5, bbb, bbb*-1)
```

However, I do not want to call it twice, because the mask is the same for both. So, if there is a way to get this result in one call of the ifelse command in Octave or Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your mask as an anonymous function and apply it with `bsxfun`:

```matlab
mask = @(x, y) ifelse(y > 5, x, x*-1);
bsxfun(mask, [aaa; bbb], ccc)
```

Output:

```
ans =

  -90  -80   70   60
  -10  -15   20   30
```

Comment: What if I need different operations on aaa and bbb? I mean how can I multiply aaa by -1, and bbb by -2, in this case?

Comment: I found how to do it. When I update the mask and format of bsxfun's output as below, I can also run different operations on aaa and bbb:
mask = @(x, y) ifelse (y > 5, {x(1); x(2)}, {x(1)*-1; x(2)*-2});
res = cell2mat(bsxfun(mask, [aaa; bbb], ccc));